# getting trouble in display float value with two decimals after point in UILabel iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I stopped at one issue, it might be small but i'm not getting.

My float value is **39.9959946**.

floatValue=**39.9959946**

I want to show **39.99** in UILabel, getting problem in this help me.

```
lblValue.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",floatValue];
```

Getting output is 40.00. but i want 39.99.

Comment: Did you try nsnumberformatter ?

Comment: NOt tried yet..

Comment: Check @ivarun answer it will be helpful

Comment: @srinivasreddy did my answer worked for you?

Comment: yes @ivarun..Thank you

Comment: @srinivasreddy could you please accept answer? It will helps other to identify correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this it will work for me.

Objective c

```
float input = 39.9959946;
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

NSString *numberString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:input]];

NSLog(@"NumberString: %@", numberString);
```

Swift

```
let input:Float = 39.9959946;
let numberFormatter:NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.roundingMode = .down
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
let numberString:String = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: input))!
print(numberString)
```

You can get perfect result in Objectiv-C and Swift/

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
double val = 39.9959946;
NSNumberFormatter *numFormattor = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[numFormattor setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundFloor];
[numFormattor setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
NSLog(@"Number: %@", [numFormattor stringFromNumber:@(val)]);
```

> Number: 39.99

Comment: Thank you!! Perfect

Comment: @srinivasreddy could you please accept answer? It will helps other to identify correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 7;
    NSLog(@"Hello :%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:39.9959946]]);
```

here is the main role player.

```
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 7;
```

in your case it will be 3

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
float myFloat= 2345.678990;
NSNumberFormatter *format = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[format setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; 
[format setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];
[format setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[format setMinimumFractionDigits:2];

NSString * string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[format stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:myFloat]]];
NSLog(@"After change Float Value:%@",string);
```

The Output is: 2345.67

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had the same problem, and I have created this solution. 
This is Swift 4.1

```
func convertToDecimal(input: Float) -> String {
        let numberFormatter:NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numberFormatter.roundingMode = .down
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        let numberString:String = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: input))!
        return numberString
    }
```

it is returning String, so you can put it in UILabel.text.